# Add nofollow to custom widget posts

Tags: hooks

I would like to add the nofollow to my blog links in the custom posts widget. I think it could be done by filtering widget_posts_args but I am a bit lost on how to tweak that function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.. copied the class to functions.php
renamed the class and used this call

function wpmic_register_custom_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'mic_WP_Widget_Recent_Posts' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpmic_register_custom_widgets' );